# Sci Fi book about humans and synths

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm searching for the title and author of this book. I really liked the premise but couldn't pick it up. Here's what I can remember from it!

1. It's about two separate races: humans and Synths
2. The main character is a young male pilot who lives in a city surrounded by a forest.
3. (I think) He flies his ship and it crashes in the forest
4. He meets a synth girl and it becomes a romance thing (I think)
5. The cover is of the synth girl showing her fake human face and machine parts. The color is blue and white

I've been searching for this book for about a year now and I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Didn't read it yet. But the cover matches your description. https://www.amazon.de/Die-Maschinen-Roman-Universum-Band/dp/3453316363